# Django - Cannot delete or rename field in a model without errors (unknown field specified)

Tags: django

I have no idea what's going wrong, over the last few days, I've have made quite a few changes to the overall structure of my database, including adding and deleting fields and have tried making migrations this evening.

In one of my models (projects), I previously had a field named 'fk_user' which was foreign key field to the User. It worked fine but I decided it was no longer needed and deleted it at some point, however now i am getting the error

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (fk_user)
> specified for projects

I've had this error several times in the past caused by deleted fields and have spent many hours searching for solutions only to give up in frustration and create a new database to solve the problem, which isn't an issue at this stage. This time however, despite clearing all pycache files, creating a new empty database and referencing this new database in the settings - it is giving me the same error when I try to run migrations.

The only thing that solves it is adding any field to the model with the name 'fk_user', if I do this I can successfuly run migrations and migrate. However even after this, if I try to edit the name or delete the field, I'm given the same error again.

What is going wrong with this? I know it's telling me that it can't find a field that should be there but how do I tell it either ignore that or wipe everything and start again?

Comment: Try deleting all your migrations, except for the initials, and then run your migrations again.

Comment: i've deleted all the files in migration folder except for __init__.py however this hasn't worked, is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check your forms.py. The problem may occur if there is a reference for deleted or renamed field.